# Como fazer o Scroll centralizar nos elementos que estão dentro do container?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, user-interface

Imagine que eu tenho uma galeria de imagens que está dentro de um *container*. Porém cada imagem da galeria tem um tamanho conforme a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu gostaria de fazer é um *snap*, para que na hora do `scroll` em certo momento o elemento alvo vá para o contro do `container` conforme esse gif. Repare que em determinado momento o `scroll` meio que "automaticamente" centraliza no próximo elemento!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Existe alguma forma de fazer isso só com CSS?***

Comment: Boa pergunta. Só uma dúvida, você quer que a imagem mais próxima do centro centralize ao soltar o *scroll* ou no meio do *dragging* do *scroll*?

Comment: @fernandosavio Na verdade não quero algo em específico nem nada, quero que quando a imagem se aproximar do centro ela meio que centraliza automaticamente, não precisa ser quando soltar o scroll não

Comment: Tô quebrando cabeça pensando em como fazer isso com JS, com CSS vai ser bem improvável. hahaha

Comment: @fernandosavio vc deveria frequentar mais o Chat da comunidade :) https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha

Comment: Pra quem quiser desbravar: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/css-scroll-snap

Comment: @sam estou aqui esperando alguém com boa vontade... :)

Comment: Eu não conhecia essas propriedades, mas é interessante. Se alguém responder vou aprender :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim! Você precisa dar ao contêiner a regra `scroll-snap-type: x mandatory`, no caso do scroll horizontal, e aos filhos dê a regras `scroll-snap-align: center`.

Agora à resposta mais completa. Quanto ao **contêiner** você deverá passar dois parâmetros:

1) Quanto ao rigor, o snap pode ser 'mandatory' ou 'proximity'. No primeiro caso, o snap será rigoroso e no segundo o snap funcionará apenas se o elemento estiver próximo da posição.

2) Quanto ao eixo, o snap pode ocorrer nos eixos x, y ou 'both' (ambos).

Você também poderá criar um padding aplicável apenas ao snap. Por exemplo, se você quiser que os itens se alinhem à esquerda, mas que não toquem o lado esquerdo, poderia adicionar a regra `scroll-padding: 10px`.

Exemplos:

```
#container{
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}
#container{
    scroll-snap-type: both proximity;
    scroll-padding: 10px;
}
```

Quanto aos **elementos**:

Você deverá dizer se deseja alinhá-los pelo início, centro ou fim com a regra `scroll-snap-align` em "start", "center" ou "end".
Além disso, de forma análoga ao padding do contêiner, você pode utilizar `scroll-margin` para definir margens aplicáveis apenas para o scroll.

Exemplos:

```
#container>.element{
    scroll-snap-align: center;
}
#container>.element{
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    scroll-margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Fonte: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/css-scroll-snap